# Реализация REST API

Tags: java, rest

На днях ради интереса кинул резюме в компанию, прислали предварительное тестирование. Сказано реализовать REST API для работы с содержимым текстовых файлов. Что такое REST API, простыми словами? И какие (желательно простые) реализации подобного (для любой задачи, не обязательно работа с файлами)  есть на C#/Java? Буду благодарен любому ответу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на такой же вопрос отсюда: https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=390415

> API социальных сетей - это вполне типичные примеры реализации REST
> API.
>
> REST (RESTful) - это общие принципы организации взаимодействия
> приложения/сайта с сервером посредством протокола HTTP. Особенность
> REST в том, что сервер не запоминает состояние пользователя между
> запросами - в каждом запросе передаётся информация, идентифицирующая
> пользователя (например, token, полученный через OAuth-авторизацию) и
> все параметры, необходимые для выполнения операции.
>
> Всё взаимодействие с сервером сводится к 4 операциям (4 - это
> необходимый и достаточный минимум, в конкретной реализации типов
> операций может быть больше):
>
> 1. получение данных с сервера (обычно в формате JSON, или XML)
> 2. добавление новых данных на сервер
> 3. модификация существующих данных на сервере
> 4. удаление данных на сервере
>
> Операция получения данных не может приводить к изменению состояния
> сервера.
>
> Для каждого типа операции используется свой метод HTTP-запроса:
>
> 1. получение - GET
> 2. добавление - POST
> 3. модификация - PUT
> 4. удаление - DELETE
>
> Т.е. :
>
> GET-запрос /rest/users - получение информации о всех пользователях
> GET-запрос /rest/users/125 - получение информации о пользователе с
> id=125 POST-запрос /rest/users - добавление нового пользователя
> PUT-запрос /rest/users/125 - изменение информации о пользователе с
> id=125 DELETE-запрос /rest/users/125 - удаление пользователя с id=125

Статья о REST API на Java:

https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/480564/

Есть REST-фреймворки для Java, например, Spark:

http://sparkjava.com/